# Django: Want a ManyRelatedManager, getting ManyToManyField instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

So in my project I am trying to extend the User model to a Staff class and the Group model to a PermGroup class. However, when I save a PermGroup in the Staff's groups field (inherited from User) it only saves the PermGroup object as a Group and all of the fields and methods I defined in my PermGroup class are stripped away. So I decided the best course of action would be to override the groups field. From an earlier stackoverflow question I found and Django documentation, this should work.

```
class Staff(User):
    User.groups = models.ManyToManyField('PermGroup', blank=True)
```

I need to use 'PermGroup' because the class shows up later in the file, and PermGroup has a field that relies on the Staff class, so if i switched the order  I would have the same problem, only in the PermGroup class.

Now the problem I am having is that groups is now a ManyToManyField object where all the other "manytomany" fields are ManyRelatedManagers. I want groups to be a ManyRelatedManager but I do not know how.

Is it possible to get groups to be a ManyRelatedManager when I initiatize it using the 'PermGroup' model call?

If my approach is wrong and you can suggest an alternative to saving PermGroups in the Staff class. I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have your Staff be a standard model with a ForeignKey (OneToOneField, to be more exact) to his/her corresponding User?

And, to remove the circular dependency problem, you just need to make one dependent on the other.  For instance, the PermGroup model could have a field of a ManytoMany of the Staff members in that group. There's no need for Staff to have a PermGroup, because if you wanted to see what groups a member belongs to, you'd just do something like this:

```
groups_theyre_in = PermGroups.objects.filter(staff_members__id=id_were_looking_for)
```

Comment: Ok we've worked around it to remove PermGroup's dependency on Staff.

My original issue still remains though. When I override User's group field

    "User.groups = models.ManyToManyField(PermGroup, blank=True)"

It still makes groups into a ManyToManyField object and not a ManyRelatedManager object. How can I override this field without its object changing?